Exception when setting Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ChartArea.Width
I create excel sheets with charts. It works OK, I get the excel file with a number of sheets,  but i cannot set the ChartArea.Width or ChartArea.Height properties of the charts. I get an exception saying the object is locked.
Very stripped code example:
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
 
try {
    //Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = true;

    //Get a new workbook.
    oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add());
     
    // create a chart
    oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
    Excel._Chart oChart = (Excel._Chart)oWB.Charts.Add();
    double w = oChart.ChartArea.Width;

    oChart.ChartArea.Width = 800;
    oChart.ChartArea.Height = 800;


the last 2 lines throw exception saying the object is locked and cannot be changed. I can change it manually but not from code. All Microsoft documentation I can find says it is possible to set the ChartArea properties, and I cannot find anything about locked objects or how to unlock them.
What might be wrong?
tried
oChart.ChartArea.Width = 800;
expected property changed.
result is exception as above
